# Wireless disconnects at random after upgrade to Ubuntu 10.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04

After upgrading my home server from Ubuntu 8.10 to 10.4 my wireless seemingly drops out, even though my IRC client keeps it's connection to the servers, so it looks like the machine just stops taking wireless requests. A `ping` will give a me this

> Request timeout for icmp_seq 27
>
> ping: sendto: Host is down

After a while the machine just starts responding again, without any interaction from me. When the machine comes back, this is what `dmesg` gives me

> [   18.296288] wlan0: direct probe to AP 00:1b:63:22:a4:5f (try 1)
>
> [   18.296350] wlan0: deauthenticating
>   from 00:1b:63:22:a4:5f by local choice
>   (reason=3)
>
> [   18.296440] wlan0: direct probe to
>   AP 00:1b:63:22:a4:5f (try 1)
>
> [   18.298697] wlan0: direct probe
>   responded
>
> [   18.298706] wlan0: authenticate
>   with AP 00:1b:63:22:a4:5f (try 1)
>
> [   18.306836] wlan0: authenticated
>
> [   18.306886] wlan0: associate with
>   AP 00:1b:63:22:a4:5f (try 1)
>
> [   18.309396] wlan0: RX AssocResp
>   from 00:1b:63:22:a4:5f (capab=0x411
>   status=0 aid=2)
>
> [   18.309402] wlan0: associated
>
> [   18.310187]
>   ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link
>   becomes ready
>
> [   18.447742] apm: BIOS version 1.2
>   Flags 0x03 (Driver version 1.16ac)
>
> [   18.447748] apm: overridden by
>   ACPI.
>
> [   19.163282] padlock: VIA PadLock
>   not detected.
>
> [   28.352022] wlan0: no IPv6 routers
>   present
>
> kjes@brin:~$

`lspci`

> 02:07.0 Network controller: RaLink RT2561/RT61 rev B 802.11g

It's on a wireless network with WPA2, the machine worked without any problems on the same wireless network since Ubuntu 8.10 was the most resent version, and there have been no changes to my network recently. Even though the server drops out, everything else on the network keeps working like normal.

Comment: I noticed today that the server stops responding to `ping`, `nmap`, `telnet` and `ssh` on the local network, but the webserver continued to show my webpage and ping responded when I used the URL for the server, however I could not connect to `SSH` when using the URL.